# Regarding Froyo Android 2.2

Tags: android-2.2-froyo

A new android manifest file attribue android:installLocation can be used to install application to sdcard or phone memory. It can have a value "auto" . What's that mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you have no preference for where the application is installed; it can be installed in either the sdcard or the main memory, depending on the device's preferences.

Comment: hmm so if it depends on device pref only so can we give user a chance to modify it?

Comment: yep, in that case the phone will chose the default install location, but they can go in to their "manage apps" area and right next to the uninstall button will be an option to move the app to the other location then the one it was installed to. (either Phone or SD Card)